# Are some of the axioms of a norm of a vector space unnecessary?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a homework problem where my task is to find out if some of the axioms of a norm of a vector space are unnecessary, meaning they can be derived from other axioms (I presume from the problem statement). The axioms of a norm $||\cdot||$ of vector space $X$ with elements $\textbf{x}$ are:

> $(1) \;\;\; ||\textbf{x}||\geq 0$
>
> $(2) \;\;\; ||\textbf{x}|| = 0 \;\leftrightarrow \;\textbf{x} = \textbf{0}$
>
> $(3)\;\;\; ||\alpha \textbf{x}|| = |\alpha| \,||\textbf{x}||, \;\text{where $\alpha$ is
>  a scalar}$
>
> $(4) \;\;\; ||\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}||\leq ||\textbf{x}|| + ||\textbf{y}||$

I think I have an answer for this but I wanted to make sure whether my answer is correct or not. I think that axioms $(1)$ and $(2)$ are unnecessary, because:

$(2)$ follows from the axiom $(3)$, by selecting $\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$ from which we get:

$$||\alpha\cdot \textbf{0}|| = ||\textbf{0}|| = |\alpha|\,||\textbf{0}||\;\;\rightarrow\;\;||\textbf{0}|| = 0$$

and then we get axiom $(2)$

$$||\textbf{x}|| = ||\textbf{0}||=0\;\;\leftrightarrow\;\;\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}.$$

Axiom $(1)$ follows also from axioms  $(3)$ and $(4)$, because by setting $\textbf{y} = -\textbf{x}$, we get:

$$ ||-\textbf{x}|| \geq ||\textbf{x} - \textbf{x}|| -||\textbf{x}|| = ||\textbf{0}|| - ||\textbf{x}||$$

$$||-\textbf{x}|| \geq -||\textbf{x}||$$

$$||\textbf{x}|| \geq -||\textbf{x}||$$

$$2||\textbf{x}|| \geq 0$$

$$||\textbf{x}|| \geq 0$$

Is my reasoning correct? So I would say that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only shown that $\|0\| = 0$, i.e. that $x = 0 \implies \|x\| = 0$. The other direction does actually not follow from $(3)$ and $(4)$. Take for example $\|\cdot\|$ defined via $\|x\| = 0$ for all $x$. Then $\|\cdot\|$ satisfies $(3)$ and $(4)$ but in $(2)$ the other direction does not hold. ($\|\cdot\|$ is then called a *seminorm*.)

That $(1)$ follows from $(3)$ and $(4)$ is right.

Comment: Thank you for your help! =) So only $(1)$ is unnecessary.

Comment: $(1)$ is completely unnecessary and the direction $\Longleftarrow$ in $(2)$ follows from $(3)$.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it =)  +1

Comment: Hi @JendrikStelzner I have one question bugging my mind yet about this :) I showed that from axiom $(3)$ I can derive that $||\textbf{0}|| = 0$. Doesn't this relation then mean that if $\textbf{x}=\textbf{0} \rightarrow ||\textbf{x}|| = 0$ and that if $||\textbf{x}|| = 0 = ||\textbf{0}|| \rightarrow \textbf{x} = \textbf{0}$, which is axiom $(2)$. But you're saying that $(2)$ does not follow from $(3)$ in both directions? Sry for extra question, sometimes things get confusing ;D

Comment: I don’t see where you get the implication $\|\mathbf{x}\| = \|\mathbf{0}\| \to \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ from. This does not follow from $(3)$ and $(4)$; just because two vectors have the same “length” does not mean that they are equal. Take for example $\|\mathbf{x}\| = 0$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in X$. Then $\|\mathbf{x}\| = |\mathbf{0}|$ for every $\mathbf{x} \in X$.

Comment: Aah, now I got it. Sorry, fool mistake for me. Understood, thank you! =)